# T4 templates: any way to make ToStringWithCulture() convert null to string.Empty instead of throwing exception?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, t4

When I provide an object to a T4 template with nullable properties, unless I explicitly write `<#= obj.Property ?? string.Empty #>` the `ToStringWithCulture(object objectToConvert)` method that is generated for the template throws an `ArgumentNullException` if the property is null. Is there any neat or elegant way to override this behavior so that I don't have to pepper null coalescing all over my templates?

Answer (score 4):

lloyd's answer is basically correct but incomplete. You will have to override the base template class for the change to persist even after you edit your template. Here's how:

1. Create a new base class for the template, for example `TemplateBase.cs`
2. Copy the contents of your current auto-generated template base class to `TemplateBase.cs`. The auto-generated base class can be found under your .tt template in Visual Studio. It's called `YourTemplateBase` and it contains (among other things) the `public class ToStringInstanceHelper` mentioned in the question.
3. Add the following declaration to `TemplateBase.cs`:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Required to make this class a base class for T4 templates
   /// </summary>
   public abstract string TransformText();
   ```
4. Add the base template declaration in `YourTemplate.tt`:

   ```
   <#@ template language="C#" Inherits="TemplateBase" #>
   ```

   After this change, your template will no longer generate a base class.
5. Make the following edit in `ToStringInstanceHelper` nested inside `TemplateBase.cs`:

   ```
   public string ToStringWithCulture(object objectToConvert)
   {
       if (objectToConvert == null)
           return "";
       ...
   }
   ```

Credit to mnaoumov: https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/t4-runtime-templates-base-class/

Answer (score 0):

Mnaoumov's Solution. Change the [base template class](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/t4-templates-and-null-in-expression-block/)

```
public string ToStringWithCulture(object objectToConvert)
{
    if (objectToConvert == null)
        return "";
    ...
}
```

Comment: The base class will be regenerated each time you edit the template.